# access parent div from inside iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, cross-domain

Have a `div` inside which have an `iframe` - which on button(within iframe) click will redirect to a page on my domain - here on this new page - `onload` event when I do

```
$('#ParentDIV',window.parent.document).hide();
```

Getting Error: `Permission denied to access property 'document`

Here the redirected page is on my domain - But I see my redirected page and the script tags are inside `<iframe>` -

Comment: iframe src is in server from parent?

Comment: iframe src is in different domain - inside my domain's div - the redirected page is on my domain

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: who ever down voted my question, just because you could becos  you have 15+ reputation :) - try to understand the validity of the question - I was just able to solve my problem - and it is perfectly working - so please don't do just because you can - mods please try to look out for such people.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with javascript for security, has withdrawn support such executions.
The url of the iframe should be in the same domain as the document, and this also includes the subdomain.

Example:

```
www.host.com -> my.host.com [not working!]
www.host.com -> www.host.com [Works!]
www.host.com -> host.com [not working!]
host.com -> host.com [works!]
```

**The idea is to avoid injecting the code of others.**

But you can do some things...With Ajax?: yes!

If you need to get data from an external server, it is good to have this:
Ideally, the external server headers have:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

And use jQuery with this code:

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'https://www.host.com/',
    data: myData,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
    beforeSend: setHeader
});
```